# How i can fix this issue?? i can't compile my flutter web

Tags: html, flutter, dart

How i can fix this ??

flutter build web

Building with sound null safety

Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js'
instead.
/C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_screenutil-5.3.1/lib/screenutil_init.dart:23:54:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window),
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_riverpod-1.0.3/lib/src/framework.dart:275:26:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart:419:19:
  Error: The argument type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type
  'Future<Map<String, dynamic>> Function(Map<String, String>)'.
- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  callback: () async {
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart:433:19:
  Error: The argument type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type
  'Future<Map<String, dynamic>> Function(Map<String, String>)'.
- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  callback: () async {
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:357:24:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:468:24:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar.dart:452:22:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_disposable.dart:20:22:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => onReady());
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_notifier.dart:130:22:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => onReady());
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_controllers.dart:90:20:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_controllers.dart:96:20:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/router_report.dart:53:22:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-3.2.0/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart:109:29:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'PaintingBinding' which excludes null.
- 'PaintingBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/binding.dart').
  () => PaintingBinding.instance?.imageCache?.evict(key),
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-3.2.0/lib/src/image_provider/multi_image_stream_completer.dart:152:22:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance?.scheduleFrameCallback(_handleAppFrame);
  ^
  /C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/material_floating_search_bar-0.3.6/lib/src/util/util.dart:18:18:
  Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart'
  ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => callback());
  ^
  Error: Compilation failed.

Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...                             24.2s
Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.

Comment: could you share your flutter doctor output?

Comment: I've found here the solution for that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851542/flutter-build-web-builds-without-sound-null-safety-and-runs-on-error

Answer (score 0):

I got this type of issue but it solved for me with

> flutter run -d chrome --web-hostname localhost --web-port 5000
> Try running this command.