# Flutter upgrade to 3.13 generates compile problems with flutter libraries

Tags: flutter

I've just upgraded to Flutter 3.13 and now my Flutter Windows app fails to compile..

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.3086], locale en-GB)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
```

The following errors are reported...

```
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
/C:/Users/Ian/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/sliver_tools-0.2.10/lib/src/sliver_stack.dart:282:55: Error: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'.
 - 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('../../sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
 - 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
      final AbstractNode? targetParent = renderObject.parent;
                                                      ^
/C:/Users/Ian/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/sliver_tools-0.2.10/lib/src/sliver_stack.dart:283:54: Error: The method 'markNeedsLayout' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
 - 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsLayout'.
      if (targetParent is RenderObject) targetParent.markNeedsLayout();
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

**The issue occure when you update your Flutter version to the latest 3.13.0**

- Check-in your pubspec.yaml file all dependencies you have used.
- Any dependency is used **sliver_tools** dependency. (Check below-attached ss)
- Update that dependency's latest version.

[image]

Comment: In my case the problem was with an old version of the `sliver_tools` which is a dependency for `infinite_scroll_pagination`, updating which version gave me a resolution. You can check which packages are using the `sliver_tools` on it's page on pub.dev (right side menu `More` → `Packages that depend on sliver_tools`) and find them in your project to give an update.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at
[Flutter build web builds without sound null safety and runs on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851542/flutter-build-web-builds-without-sound-null-safety-and-runs-on-error)

Solution was to run

flutter pub upgrade and flutter pub outdated then flutter pub get and it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue when I updated the flutter version and found that the older `pubspec.lock` file was causing the issues due to some missing methods which can be resolved by either deleting the `pubspec.lock` file or running `flutter pub upgrade`.

Note: copy and save the pubspec.yaml file before running the `flutter pub upgrade` command in case of any issue.